# Subnet Creation in AWS CloudFormation fails with InvalidSubnet.Range

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating subnets within my VPC using CloudFormation. I am getting the following error during creation of all my subnets. Here is my template:

```
VpcCIDR:
    Description: VPC CIDR
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/16
  MyPubSub1CIDR:
    Description: CIDR for MyPubSub1CIDR 
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.0.0/24
  MyPubSub2CIDR:
    Description: CIDR for MyPubSub2CIDR
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.1.0/24
  MyPriSub1CIDR:
    Description: CIDR for MyPriSub1CIDR 
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.2.0/24
  MyPriSub2CIDR:
    Description: CIDR for MyPriSub2CIDR 
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.3.0/24
```

The error is:
The CIDR '10.0.1.0/24' is invalid. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidSubnet.Range; Request ID: 5b85622c-2958-4010-b5de-5c15b0937e8f)

It is the same error for the other subnets too.

Comment: no idea why, have you found the answer

Comment: Could you also provide the parts of the template where these parameters are reverenced in resources?

Comment: thank you. your comment helped!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone responded!
Never mind about this. The CIDR used for VPC was different than the default 10.0.0.0/16. In the parameters file, it was set to something different.

Looking back, the error message makes sense. I feel the error message could be made better to reflect that there is a mismatch between VPC CIDR and subnet CIDR rather than "Invalid Range" which made me think the issue is with subnet CIDR. Or I could learn to interpret the message better. I settle for the latter :)